# Why I can not display photos from my local storage with react native and expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image

I want to display the 5 most recent photos from my phone on the screen (something like a gallery app). I am using react native and expo.

How do I fetch the photos:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getPhotos();
  }, []);



const getPhotos = async () => {
    const params = {
      first: 5,
      mediaType: MediaLibrary.MediaType.photo,
      sortBy: [MediaLibrary.SortBy.creationTime],
    };
    if (after) params.after = after;
    if (!hasNextPage) return;
    await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync(params).then(processPhotos);
  };



     const processPhotos = (data) => {
    if (data.totalCount) {
      if (after === data.endCursor) return;
      const uris = data.assets;
      photos.length > 0 ? setPhotos([...photos, ...uris]) : setPhotos(uris);
      setAfter(data.endCursor);
      hasNextPage(data.hasNextPage);
    } else {
      setIsEmpty(true);
    }
  };
```

So far, so good, the images are fetched and I am setting them with `setPhotos`. When I do `console.log("photos: ", photos)` this is what I see array with the following format on the console:

```
photos:  Array [
  Object {
    "albumId": "-9334534567",
    "creationTime": 16572943,
    "duration": 0,
    "filename": "IMG_3.jpg",
    "height": 3648,
    "id": "83864",
    "mediaType": "photo",
    "modificationTime": 165375000,
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_3.jpg",
    "width": 2736,
  },
  Object {
    "albumId": "-29802856",
    "creationTime": 1659618,
    "duration": 0,
    "filename": "IMG_4.jpg",
    "height": 3648,
    "id": "83863",
    "mediaType": "photo",
    "modificationTime": 164534345450,
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_4.jpg",
    "width": 2736,
  },
  Object {
    "albumId": "-373901",
    "creationTime": 1659312372,
    "duration": 0,
    "filename": "IMG_5.jpg",
    "height": 3648,
    "id": "83862",
    "mediaType": "photo",
    "modificationTime": 165934000,
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_5.jpg",
    "width": 2736,
  },
]
```

Then I want to render the photos within flatlist. For the time being I don't care about the styling, I just want simply to display the photos:

```
return (
      <FlatList
        data={photos}
        numColumns={numColumns}
        key={numColumns}
        renderItem={(item) => {
          console.log("THIS PART IS NOT BEING RENDERED!")
          console.log("item: ", item);
          return (
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                borderColor: "pink",
                borderWidth: 2,
              }}
              source={{
                uri: item.item.uri,
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(_, index) => index}
        onEndReached={() => getPhotos()}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        initialNumToRender={24}
        getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
      />
    );
```

When I do `console.log` of the item, this is what I see:

```
Object {
  "index": 34,
  "item": Object {
    "albumId": "-173933243242321",
    "creationTime": 1658516165017,
    "duration": 0,
    "filename": "IMG_5.jpg",
    "height": 3648,
    "id": "83782",
    "mediaType": "photo",
    "modificationTime": 1658516166000,
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_5.jpg",
    "width": 2736,
  },
  "separators": Object {
    "highlight": [Function highlight],
    "unhighlight": [Function unhighlight],
    "updateProps": [Function updateProps],
  },
}
```

I believe the problem is within

```
source={{
    uri: item.item.uri,
}}
```

but I don't know how to fix it. Something worth mentioning is that when I use `uri: item.uri` I see the pink border but I don't see any image being displayed. When I use  `uri: item.item.uri,` I don't see anything, the screen is just white.